# Unable to login for graphical session on Mint + Not available space on filesystem

Tags: linux-mint, login, disk-usage, session

I've been trying to start a graphical session with all users on my system but I've been always **reverted to the login screen**.

After **initiating a terminal with (Ctrl+Alt+F1)** from there, I've been able to start terminal sessions with all users, so this means passwords are not the problem.

With a superuser and the terminal I've been able to check what I was suspecting: `$ df -h` shows **no available space** on `/dev/sda1` (filesystem root) despite partition size is 64 GB and 61 GB are used. The fact is that Mint was warning me about this but I thought 2 GB free was enough to keep running the system. My mistake was clear when I tried to start up next day!

So I've been moving files from `/home` to another partition and removed apt cache executing `$ (sudo) apt clean` but `$ df -h` keeps saying there's no available space after that. Therefore if this is the problem, how do I fix it in order to be able to start a graphical session? How much space is needed or should I reserve to prevent this happen in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Well, on cleaning user folder, `/home/myuser`, I made 4GB free space but it seems this doesn't count to be able to open graphical environment.

After cleaning apt cache I got 1GB according to `$ df -h`, and I was able to open a graphical session. I don't know why didn't work the first time.

Later, I removed **`timeshift`** snapshots (20GB). It seems to me like this app is like a disk worm, whatever useful they want to sell, I don't buy it. Finally I've been cleaning some logs from `/var/log`, `/run/log` and cleaning some temps at `/var/tmp`.

Right now things work.